# testng rSpec saving or update on a has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rspec

I have a simple `User` and `Score` class and an `IndexController`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scores
  attr_accessible :scores_attributes, :scores
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :scores
end

class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :time_elapsed
  belongs_to :user
end
```

My IndexController (simplified)

```
def setHighscore
  existing_user = User.find_by_random_token(session[:user][:random_token])
  existing_user.scores.new(time_elapsed: params[:time_elapsed])
  existing_user.save
end
```

And my spec

```
describe IndexController do
  it "appends a highscore to an existing user" do
    user = User.create!(valid_session[:user])
    existing_user = User.should_receive(:find_by_random_token).with(random_token).and_return(user)

     existing_user.scores.should_receive(:new).with(time_elapsed: 400)

     post :setHighscore, valid_params, valid_session
end
```

I got this error

```
RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: (#<RSpec::Mocks::MessageExpectation:0x007fb4fa2b67c0>).new({:time_elapsed=>400})
    expected: 1 time with arguments: ({:time_elapsed=>400})
    received: 0 times with arguments: ({:time_elapsed=>400})
```

How do I correctly test when I do an `update_attribute(blah)` or `model.model.create(blah)` or model.model.new(blah)` ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think `Score` gets method `new` so try to change code to

```
Score.should_receive(:new).with(time_elapsed: 400)
```

Comment: Ok, I thought too complex. Done: `expected: ({:time_elapsed=>400}) got: ({:time_elapsed=>"400"}, {})` looks quite good, but where did the second hash come from?

Comment: I never met this but it looks correctly if check the [description](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/new/class) of the method `new`. There are some options in input params.

Comment: I've now have `Score.should_receive(:new).with({:time_elapsed => 400}, {})` but still an error occurs: `NoMethodError: undefined method '[]=' for nil:NilClass`. How did I get running this very simple thing?

Comment: I looked through my tests with similar logic. I have the similar test, if translate it into your terms (example): 1. change controller to `existing_user.scores.build(time_elapsed: params[:time_elapsed])` 2. modify test `Score.should_receive(:build).with({:time_elapsed=>400})

Comment: Thank you.... ehm.. but now it does not count up anymore: `expected: 1 time with arguments: ({:time_elapsed=>400})
    received: 0 times with arguments: ({:time_elapsed=>400})`

Comment: 1. try to check if test `should_receive` without `with` passes successfully (it will mean that the problem in params) 2. if #1 then try to use `hash_including` something like this `Score.should_receive(:build).with(hash_including(time_elapsed: 400))`

Comment: Without the `with` I got the same error: `expected: 1 time with arguments: ({:time_elapsed=>400}) received: 0 times with arguments: ({:time_elapsed=>400}) ` When I make the whole process in my console the behavior works like expected. :-/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38347/discussion-between-gotva-and-jan)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware what causes this issue but I ended up using one of this two terms:

```
existing_user.scores.should have(1).item
```

but also this one works

```
Score.count.should == 1
```

Comment: you can also test that exactly your post change count of Score `expect{ post(...) }.to change(Score, :count)`

Comment: `expect(post :setHighscore, valid_params, valid_session).to change(Score, :count)` raises an `NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for #`

Comment: no :) you should place into expect the action which change the count `expect(post(:setHighscore, valid_params, valid_session)).to change(Score, :count)`

Comment: Raises the same... `NoMethodError: undefined method 'call' for #<ActionController::TestResponse:0x007fd63fb022b0>`